# vim "autoindent" // pattern

Tags: vim

My terminal is 160 characters wide.

I use VIM.

Is there a way to tell vim:

when you see "//", autoindent it to start @ width 80?

(And haave it also affected when I highlight a region and hit =)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually mean *indent*, or are you trying to align comments? That is, is there non-whitespace text before the "//"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to see about `:filetype indent plugin on`

You may also want to look at this plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294

Generally, it sounds like a bad idea to arbitrarily indent comments that far in. Usually comments should be on the same indentation as the code, or just after the code if it is on the same line.

If you're really sure this is what you want to do, you could make a mapping or an abreviation:

```
:iab // <ctrl-o>80i<space><esc>A//<space>
```

or

```
:imap // <ctrl-o>80i<space><esc>A//<space>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the following line in your .vimrc file.

> set autoindent
>
> set textwidth=80

Comment: I don't claim to know a lot about .vimrc files, but I can't imagine how that will answer the question since it doesn't even do any sort of pattern search for "//". Can you explain how this works for a user like me who's still learning?

Comment: That is probably NOT what you want.  It has nothing to do with aligning anything.

Comment: He was probably meaning to say "set tabstop=80" but you *really* don't want that either.